# NSSplitView save and restore splitter position when switching between Vertical and Horizontal layout

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

In my app I use NSSplitView which has ability to switch between vertical and horizontal layout using `- (void)setVertical:(BOOL)flag` method. The problem is that when user change layout, splitter always restore its position on 50%/50%.

NSSplitView has an autosave possibility for its divider, but it doen't save values for both layouts.

What is the best way to handle this? Save subviews rects in NSUserDefault on every resize and splitter move and restore them when layout switched? Is it looks good? Is there a better solution.

Comment: I found myself very helpful answer here http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SavingNSSplitViewPosition

Comment: working link: https://cocoadev.github.io/SavingNSSplitViewPosition/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, autosave doesn't work with splitter position (not sure why). I ended up doing exactly what you suggested: saving rects in NSUserDefaults.

Additionally, there is excellent [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) with its Split View, which should work OK with regards to split position. Keep in mind though, that plugins are not (hopefully yet) supported in version 4 of our IDE ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about XCode 4... Hopefully I have uninstalled 4 and replaced with 3.2 :)

Comment: BTW, I've tried BWSplitView and it resets splitter positions when switching between vertical and horizontal too.